# Passing Data Between Scenes (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

How do I pass information in SpriteKit from one scene to another? In my game I have two scenes, the GameScene and the GameOverScene. The score is displayed in the GameScene as it increases, but how do I send this information to the second scene?

This function is called when the player runs out of lives which changes the scene.

```
 func changeScene(){

    let secondScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    secondScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)
}
```

This is my gameOverScene

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

var playAgainLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
var currentScore: Int
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
var highScore = 0
var highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
var gameScene = GameScene()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    playAgainLabel.text = "Click To Play Again!"
    playAgainLabel.fontSize = 30
    playAgainLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    playAgainLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
    self.addChild(playAgainLabel)

    if currentScore > highScore {
        highScore = currentScore
    }

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(currentScore)
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 20
    scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/1.4)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

    highScoreLabel.text = "Best: " + String(highScore)
    highScoreLabel.fontSize = 20
    highScoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    highScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 1.6)
    self.addChild(highScoreLabel)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    let playingScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    playingScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
    let fadeTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(playingScene, transition: fadeTransition)
}
```

}
}

Comment: please be more specific in your code

Answer (score 11):

For instance, your `GameOverScene` could be something like this:

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {
    var object: SomeObject!
}
```

Now, in your changeScene:

```
func changeScene(){
    let secondScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    secondScene.scaleMode = scaleMode

    secondScene.object = somethingInFirstSceneThatNeedToBePassed //here we do the passing

    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass **SKScene** and create a new **initializer** with arguments that you want to pass. As you transition from **GameScene** to second scene, create second scene by using the initializer you created and pass the score. Then present the second scene.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What arguments should I put in the initializer? And should it be in the game scene or in the game over scene?