# Passing data between SpriteKit scenes (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have been following an old Ray Wenderlich tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1514-introduction-to-the-sprite-kit-scene-editor and have encountered a problem. I have run up against this problem numerous times and even found a "solution" on the stackoverflow  site: [Passing Data Between Scenes (SpriteKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680355/passing-data-between-scenes-spritekit)

This is the same code as the tutorial (with a few tweaks as it was written in Swift 2). I feel it a very simply elegant solution and not full of code using NSdefaults etc.

This is the call to the new scene, please note the **soundToPlay** object:

```
func gameOver(didWin: Bool) {
   let menuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
   menuScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
   menuScene.soundToPlay = didWin ? "fear_win.mp3" : "fear_lose.mp3"
   let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
   self.view?.presentScene(menuScene, transition: transition)
}
```

And this is the scene I am calling:

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {

   var soundToPlay: String!

   override func sceneDidLoad() {

      self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0, green:0, blue:0, alpha: 1)

      // Setup label
      let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
      label.text = "Press anywhere to play again!"
      label.fontSize = 55
      label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
      label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

      addChild(label)

      // Play sound
      if let soundToPlay = soundToPlay {
         run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(soundToPlay, waitForCompletion: false))
      }
}
```

The data is never passed and the object has a value of **nil**

I suspect it's something that has changed in Swift as the tutorial is very old as is the suggested "solution" on the previous **stackoverflow** question.

If that is the case, what is now the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is anything else accessing soundToPlay? It shouldn't be failing on you from what I can see, so either you have a different MenuScene, or something else is accessing soundToPlay. BTW, you can use `userData` and avoid having to make a custom class for your Menu. Unless you plan on adding functionality, avoid custom classes. There is a quirks that irks me due to a bad tutorial.  `let menuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size);   menuScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill` is ugly code.  I recommend setting a constant static size or load an SKS file. When you are able to create chatrooms, I can explain why. 2)

Comment: I have just checked and it is only used on the code I have cut & paste. It is a very basic game that taught how to use the scene editor, unfortunately, a scene editor bug that had problems with adding textures to colorspritenodes lead me to code all the sprites rather than the scene editor. You other comment is interesting as all tutorials (and I have done a fair few) have the ugly code you point out. In my ignorance, I have avoided SKS files and tried to do everything programatically. Thank you

Comment: A lot of the tutorials make the same mistakes. Unfortunately, they are more concerned with getting things working, instead of using the API to its fullest potential.  Even official apple samples are guilty of doing this.

Comment: Yes, once you have learned the basics, it would nice to have a site that sets out swift conventions, best programming practices. I taught myself from the Apple everyone can code and spent more time working out the bugs introduced by following the tutorials. Thank goodness for stackoverflow

Comment: Anyway, add a print statement in your sceneDidLoad to check how many times it is called

Comment: Could you email me the project? knight0fdragon@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sound is that you are setting the variable after you call sceneDidLoad (this happens during init), so the sound will not play.

To fix this, do this code in your `didMove` method:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    guard let soundToPlay = soundToPlay else {fatalError("Unable to find soundToPlay")}
    run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(soundToPlay, waitForCompletion: false))

}
```

The actual issue to your crashing is not visible here.

`SKTransition`s are bugged when you use `SKLightNode`, so by calling a scene with a transition, it is going to crash.  `SKTransition`s have always been bugged with the introduction of Metal, so the only thing you can do is report it to apple and pray they do not tell you it is intentional.

As of now, keep track of all your light sources, and when you transition, set the `isEnabled` property to `false`.

You may need to create a screen shot of your scene prior to disabling the light source to not have it look silly.

Comment: Thank you very much, adding the didMove to view fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, as you reload the scene (`let menuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)`) you are resetting all the variables that were defined.

What you could do is use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults):

```
func gameOver(didWin: Bool) {
   let menuScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
   menuScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
   let soundToPlay = didWin ? "fear_win.mp3" : "fear_lose.mp3"
   UserDefaults.standard.set(soundToPlay, forKey: "soundToPlay")
   let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
   self.view?.presentScene(menuScene, transition: transition)
}
```

And:

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {
   var soundToPlay: String!
   override func sceneDidLoad() {

      self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0, green:0, blue:0, alpha: 1)

      // Setup label
      let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
      label.text = "Press anywhere to play again!"
      label.fontSize = 55
      label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
      label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

      addChild(label)

      // Play sound
      if let soundToPlay = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "soundToPlay") {
         run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(soundToPlay, waitForCompletion: false))
      }
}
```

Then, put this in your AppDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate` function:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "soundToPlay")
}
```

If you do not put that in the AppDelegate then soundToPlay will remain after closing the app altogether.

I don't know if `UserDefaults` is the best way to do this, but I've struggled with this when I was making my `iOS` app and I just did this. So if anyone else has a better answer, please notify me as well!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. A couple of points, I would like to avoid using UserDefaults as I believe there is a reason that the code should work. Surely two sources (Ray Wenderlich and Stackoverflow) cannot be wrong. Secondly, I set the soundToPlay object after the reset as I do with the scaleMode and scaleMode object data is passed across unaffected. Either way, if I do not get an answer I will use your useful suggestion of UserDefaults

Comment: @GaryNials of course. If a better answer is posted please notify me so I can use it!

Comment: Unless you plan on saving to the hard disk, you shouldn't use userdefaults.  I actually discourage using it at all for anything other than settings.  I recommend using `userData`.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon oh... does `userData` work as some sort of RAM version of `userDefaults`? Interesting...

Comment: Userdata is custom data you want to attach to a node

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I know, but I thought you meant there is some kind of general user data. If you use it like this, as resetting OP's scene resets the node, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes it would, it would work exactly the same way as it would in the user code, except you wouldnt use a property.

Comment: You would do it like this: https://pastebin.com/vLyNHiri  which avoids writing to disk, and having to erase from the disk.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Interesting. I’ll improve my program with this. Thanks