# How to edit a label thats in a different scene in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

- Yes there is already a similar question but it does not give me an answer

*Back Story* - feel free to skip

I have been creating a game where you have to stop 'monsters' getting past your characters by firing projectiles at them, this is all (finally) working perfectly.

*Problem*

However, I tried to create a coin counter that would be shown whenever the scene 'flips' back to the start screen (its called playScene and the actually game is called GameScene). I was wondering how I can create a counter that is edited in a different scene to where the scoring happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Scenes (SpriteKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680355/passing-data-between-scenes-spritekit)

Comment: Is this on `iOS` or `macOS`?

Comment: @Koen this is iOS mate, any help you could give would be massively appreciated

Comment: can't you use delegate or notification to pass the parameter to the scene that you came from?

Comment: It should be something like `playScene.counter.text = "\(score)"` assuming you have a property `playScene` that points to your start screen.

Comment: @SteveIves is there anyway you could be more specific? I am going to try upload a link for the source code so you can see it

Comment: @skullamunger: Welcome to SO. Please don't just link to a complete project and ask someone to fix it. It's better to post the relevant code snippets here and then explain what you are trying to do and what doesn't work. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Koen of course, sorry man. I just thought it would be easier to include the whole project as it revolves around different scenes and the code within them

Comment: @skullamunger Without looking at your code, heres a more detailed descriotion: Have a property in gameScene called ‘playScene’ which is an SKScene. When playScene loads gameScene, before segueing to it, get playScene to update this property so it points back to itself (playScene) `gameScene.playScene = self`. Then in gameScene, the ‘playScene’property will point back to pkayScene and can be used to update pkayScene’s properties (such as the label) assuming it’s still loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 scenes: GameScene and ScoreScene.

ScoreScene is the scene where player gets redirected after he dies. Like a lost scene where you show his stats. We start by creating a global variable called `score` and set it default to 0.

```
class ScoreScene: SKScene {

    let score : Int = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        print("Score = \(score)")  // Score = 0
    }
}
```

User enters in the GameScene, kills monster and then he dies at score 87. Before presenting the ScoreScene, you pass the score.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    func change_scene()
    {
        let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 0.75)
        let next_scene = ScoreScene() // at this point, score = 0
        next_scene.score = 87         // at this point, score = 87
        self.view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

You can pass values from a scene to another by creating a global value in our case `score` and giving it a value before you `presentScene`.